# Сортировка пузырьком проблемы с выводом

Tags: python, пузырьковая-сортировка

Сам алгоритм работает, но нужно, чтобы при каждой перестановке выводился результат сортировки. То если была одна перестановка, то массив выводился в консоль один раз, если перестановка не требуется (все числа в массиве равны) тоже выводится один раз

```py
def bubble_sort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        counter = 0
        for j in range(len(array)-1-i):
            if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
                counter += 1
        if counter > 0:
            print(' '.join(map(str, array)))
        else:
            print(' '.join(map(str, array)))
            break


n = int(input())                                   # вводим 5
array = [int(x) for x in input().strip().split()]  # вводим 12 8 9 10 11

bubble_sort(array)  # ожидаем вывод вида 8 9 10 11 12 (то есть только одна строка)
                    # а получаем 8 9 10 11 12
                    #            8 9 10 11 12
```

Update
Решение, которое предложили, работает как задумано

```py
def bubble_sort(array):
    nosorting = True
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        counter = 0        
        for j in range(len(array)-1-i):
            if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
                counter += 1                
        if counter > 0:
            nosorting = False
            print(' '.join(map(str, array)))
        else:            
            break
    if nosorting == True:
        print(' '.join(map(str, array)))
        

n = int(input())
array = [int(x) for x in input().strip().split()]

bubble_sort(array)
```

Comment: Когда перестановка не требуется, counter будет иметь значение 0, а значит сработает ветка else, а значит сработает написанный в ней print, который и выводит массив второй раз

Comment: Если из else убрать print, то в случае, когда перестановка не требуется, в консоль вообще ничего не будет выводиться, а нужно чтобы выводился исходный массив. Например, подаем на ввод ```1 1 1 1```, вывод должен быть ```1 1 1 1``` Не соображу, как это реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходный массив выводить нужно всегда, то переставьте вывод в начало цикла, делайте print независимо от counter. Тогда выведется исходный массив и все изменения.

Если выводить его только в случае, когда сортировка не понадобилась, то при увеличении counter сбросьте флаг `nosorting = false` (с начальным значением true), а в самом конце вне циклов проверяйте его и тогда уже выводите массив

Comment: Спасибо. Cработало

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы список печатался только один раз достаточно сдвинуть `break` на один отступ влево, вот так:

```py
def bubble_sort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        ...
        if counter > 0:
            print(' '.join(map(str, array)))
        else:
            print(' '.join(map(str, array)))
            break  # ---
        break      # +++
```

PS: тремя минусами (`---`) отмечена удаленная строка, а тремя плюсами (`+++`) - добавленная.